# Update DynamoDB table for Provisioned Throughput

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In the API of DynamoDB there is a way to increase/decrease table Provisioned Throughput but there is some Active mode that needs to be updated, what if there is two scripts that running on the same table at the same time and one of them read and the other update the table, What's going to happened with the one that reading? Is it going to failed?

I think maybe before every reading I can check if the table is on Active mode and if not just wait until it does but each time that I'm Query/Scan the database I need to make this check. Maybe it's not necessary.

Is anyone know about this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessary, you can still read from the table when it's been updated.

EDIT:
from http://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/faqs/

Q: Does Amazon DynamoDB remain available when I ask it to scale up or down by changing the provisioned throughput?

Yes. Amazon DynamoDB is designed to scale its provisioned throughput up or down while still remaining available.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB reads are "eventually consistent", so the query/scan may not see the updated rows but the request will not fail. You can request consistent reads if you need them though (though they consume slightly more Read Capacity).

[See the docs for more information.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.ReadConsistency.html)